# Update database from dataset select in SAS

Tags: sql, sas, proc-sql

I am trying to update DB records from SAS dataset. This is what I have tried:

```
proc sql noprint;
UPDATE A
SET 
A.IP = U.IP, 
A.COUNTRY = U.COUNTRY, 
A.CREATION_DATE = U.CREATION_DATE, 
A.STATUS = U.STATUS
FROM db_table.COUNTRY A INNER JOIN SAS_dataset U 
on A.APPLICATION=U.APPLICATION;
quit;
run;
```

Getting an error:

```
106        A.IP = U.IP,
            _
            73
            76
ERROR 73-322: Expecting an =.

ERROR 76-322: Syntax error, statement will be ignored.
```

My other code with Inserts *and so forth* works fine.

Comment: Why are you using SQL instead of using the MODIFY statement in a data step?

Comment: You cannot do that in SAS SQL.  You can only do UPDATE table SET variable=value [,variable = value] [WHERE expression] ;  Each VALUE could be a sub query that returns only one value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved via sub-query

```
proc sql;
update tableA A
set var=
  (select var 
  from tableB B 
  where B.id=A.id)
where exists (
  select 1 
  from tableB B
  where B.id=A.id);
quit;
```